Concatenate List of tuples whose elements are numpy arrays
I have a list as shown below
>>> x
[
(array([1. +0.j , 0.5+0.5j, 0. +0.j , 0.5-0.5j, 1. +0.j ]), array([0.5+0.5j, 0. +0.j , 0.5-0.5j, 1. +0.j , nan+0.j ])), 
(array([1. +0.j , 0.5+0.5j, 0. +0.j , 0.5-0.5j, 1. +0.j ]), array([0.5+0.5j, 0. +0.j , 0.5-0.5j, 1. +0.j , nan+0.j ])), 
(array([1. +0.j , 0.5+0.5j, 0. +0.j , 0.5-0.5j, 1. +0.j ]), array([0.5+0.5j, 0. +0.j , 0.5-0.5j, 1. +0.j , nan+0.j ]))
]

My requirement is to concatenate this array into two 1D arrays such that the first element in each tuple being concatenated into one 1D array and second element into the second 1D array.
Expected End result
[
[1. +0.j , 0.5+0.5j, 0. +0.j , 0.5-0.5j, 1. +0.j, 1. +0.j , 0.5+0.5j, 0. +0.j , 0.5-0.5j, 1. +0.j, 1. +0.j , 0.5+0.5j, 0. +0.j , 0.5-0.5j, 1. +0.j],
[0.5+0.5j, 0. +0.j , 0.5-0.5j, 1. +0.j , nan+0.j, 0.5+0.5j, 0. +0.j , 0.5-0.5j, 1. +0.j , nan+0.j, 0.5+0.5j, 0. +0.j , 0.5-0.5j, 1. +0.j , nan+0.j]
]

Ideal solution would use some standard function in numpy library without explicit loops. Could someone please shed some light on this ?

Since you have an array of arrays (i.e. an object array), you have to use a loop, true vectorization can only work with non-object arrays

out = [np.concatenate(y) for y in zip(*x)]

Thanks. What you say appears to be correct. If you'd like, please turn this into an answer -ill accept it. Either way, thanks for helping out.

You cannot vectorize operations with object arrays (in the sense of a fast low level operation).
You have to use a loop.
You could go with:
out = [np.concatenate(y) for y in zip(*x)]

Output:
[
array([1. +0.j , 0.5+0.5j, 0. +0.j , 0.5-0.5j, 1. +0.j, 1. +0.j , 0.5+0.5j, 0. +0.j , 0.5-0.5j, 1. +0.j, 1. +0.j , 0.5+0.5j, 0. +0.j , 0.5-0.5j, 1. +0.j]),
array([0.5+0.5j, 0. +0.j , 0.5-0.5j, 1. +0.j , nan+0.j, 0.5+0.5j, 0. +0.j , 0.5-0.5j, 1. +0.j , nan+0.j, 0.5+0.5j, 0. +0.j , 0.5-0.5j, 1. +0.j , nan+0.j])
]

